# Error "Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled" while building image

Tags: docker, docker-image

I am getting the below error while building an image

```
Step 1/10 : FROM ubuntu:14.04
Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Comment: spamming my own answer, but top voted answer has issues --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/77130871/5079799

Answer (score 66):

I think the issue is that you are behind the proxy which in which case you need to write a manual configuration in Docker systemd service file. That will override the default `docker.service` file.

If you are using Docker for Windows, then simply set the default DNS to 8.8.8.8 on the "vEthernet (DockerNAT)" network adapter. But remember, this is not the best practice as you will be exposing from your office network.

In Linux environment, you could add the environment variable as you are behind HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY, as you are using port 80 or 443 respectively. As shown below in : `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf`

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/"
```

as for HTTPS_PROXY in : `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/https-proxy.conf`

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:443/"
```

Then just restart docker after deamon reload:

```
 $ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
 $ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Hope this works.

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#httphttps-proxy

Comment: No I am not behind any proxy.

Comment: (Can you modify the question with your environment) Cool then try this.. sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf

#add these lines on top and above one for home router…
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

and then restart the docker.

Comment: I'm also adding lines defining proxies inside `Dockerfile` like this: `ENV http_proxy=http...`, `ENV https_proxy=...`, `ENV= ftp_proxy=...`

Comment: The HTTPS_PROXY value should start with "http://..." not  "https://..."

Comment: If you are on windows and you are using a proxy, changing the proxy settings is way easier: Right click on Docker icon in the windows toolbar --> Settings --> Resources --> PROXIES

Comment: I have an http proxy in my environment, and this configuration worked, Thanks.

Comment: on one of me nodes exist /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf

Comment: I don't have two files for `http` and `https`. You can call the file whatever you want and have both in it, could be `the-proxy.conf`. Also, don't forget, `NO_PROXY`!

Answer (score 56):

I had the same problem and the following fix has worked for me:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22635#issuecomment-260063252

In my case I've added the following 2 `nameserver` lines to `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

before:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

after:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Comment: Correct. But what does this mean? Is Google involved in propagating Docker Hub DNS?

Comment: You need to restart the docker daemon to take the changes into account: `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Answer (score 51):

I was facing the same issue when trying to build or pull an image with Docker on Win10. Changing the DNS of the Docker `vEthernet(DockerNAT)` network adapter to `8.8.8.8` fixed it for me, as described in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22635).

To change the DNS go to *Docker (TrayIcon)* -> *Settings* -> *Resources* -> *Network* and set a *fixed DNS server* ip = `8.8.8.8`.

Changing the DNS server in the configuration of the windows network adapter worked too.

After restarting Docker is able to pull and build images again.

Version Info:

```
Windows 10 x64 Enterprise Version 1709

$ docker version
Client:
 Version:       17.12.0-ce
 API version:   1.35
 Go version:    go1.9.2
 Git commit:    c97c6d6
 Built: Wed Dec 27 20:05:22 2017
 OS/Arch:       windows/amd64

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      17.12.0-ce
  API version:  1.35 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.2
  Git commit:   c97c6d6
  Built:        Wed Dec 27 20:12:29 2017
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: true
```

Comment: Thanks !!
by the way i used clouflare's dns ( 1.1.1.1 )
its a little bit faster..

Answer (score 47):

On Mac OS X, I fixed this issue by not using the experimental virtualization framework.

`Preferences -> Experimental Features`

Comment: Confirming this fixed for me. Big Sur 11.3.1 & Intel with Docker Engine 20.10.6

Comment: Big Sur 11.3.1, m1, Docker 20.10.6 works perfectly fine now

Comment: So, how do we get this to work with Big Sur experimental VF or is this just something that can't work yet?

Comment: That's it, thanks! It worked at some point on my machine but sounds like macOS 11.3.1 broke something. Will have to try on 11.4.

Comment: This made my docker-desktop go crazy and now I can not get it to stable state nor quit even after rebooting my mac m1.

Answer (score 23):

I got the same error and it was resolved by

```
docker logout registry-1.docker.io
```

Comment: I installed docker while in VPN connection, figured out issue was related to vpn setting, but executing just this single line of command resolves the problem!

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and only found out after 30 minutes that I was on a VPN network for work which blocks other sites. I went off the VPN, and it worked :) This is definitely a network issue. When it said "not authenticated", I thought perhaps I needed some login credentials or so.

Answer (score 8):

I face this problem when performing Ansible AWX installation.

I had my own private DNS :192.168.0.254  & 192.168.0.253 but was receiving same error.

Issue got resolved after change my DNS back to 8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4.

Answer (score 6):

This error occurs on Big Sur 11.3.1, Intel when you check the box for "Use new virtualization framework" under the Experimental Features tab. Unchecking the box and restarting Docker fixed this problem for me.

Comment: I had the same problem. Doing factory reset seemed to have fixed it though.

Answer (score 4):

This may be the old one, but fixed available here

https://success.docker.com/article/i-get-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority-error-when-i-try-to-login-to-my-dtr-with-default-certificates

run following commands on each server

```sh
export DOMAIN_NAME=bootstrap.node1.local
export TCP_PORT=5000
openssl s_client -connect $DOMAIN_NAME:$TCP_PORT -showcerts </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -outform PEM | tee /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/$DOMAIN_NAME.crt
update-ca-trust
/bin/systemctl restart docker.service
```

Answer (score 3):

I also had problems with pull requests timing out.
with both

```
docker pull hello-world
kubeadm config images pull
```

Perhaps this problem started for me when upgrading the VM from ubuntu 18 to 20, but there were also many kubernetes related config changes I made, so not sure.

anyway this solution resolved it for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51648635/11416610

thanks [@nils](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10166950/nils)!

incase the above link brakes, here is a quote:

> I had the same issue yesterday. Since I am behind a company proxy, I
> had to define the http-proxy for the docker daemon in:
>
> ```
> /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf
> ```
>
> The problem was, that I misconfigured the https_proxy, how it is
> described here. I used http**s**:// in the https_proxy environment
> variable, which caused this error.
>
> This configuration works for me:
>
> ```
> cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf
>
> [Service]
> Environment=http_proxy=http://IP:PORT/
> Environment=no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1
> Environment=https_proxy=http://IP:PORT/
> ```
>
> Remember that you have to restart the docker daemon after changing
> this configuration. You can achieve this by using:
>
> ```
> systemctl daemon-reload
> systemctl restart docker
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue with registry deployed in swarm. Restart docker helps but after some time it occurs again.

Redeploy registry with docker-compose

```
sudo docker-compose up -d
```

and all works fine

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 - home PC. none of the solution worked for me. what worked is un-install docker, restart PC, "run as administrator" while installing exe. worked!!

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error. I am using a ubuntu 20.04 system

```bash
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I added the missing lines inside `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

```bash
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

This is how it looks now.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
```

Comment: Thank you! On same OS, tried a bunch of other proposed solutions but this was the one that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue on ubuntu when I am trying to build **elasticsearch**:

And I got this error:

```
ERROR: Get https://docker.elastic.co/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

It was my network connection problem. I was using VPN.
so I **disconnect my VPN connection** and it's working fine.

for some reasons, it's trying to look up the domain it seems trying to search for the domain inside the local network after I disconnect the VPN everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, my company needed to define my IP in the **White list** in order to access the cloud.docker files. So do not hesitate to tell the responsible person if you have such error.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with Windows WSL, not only do you have to set the static dns servers as mentioned above in both the Docker Desktop client, and your containers, but you also need to add

```
 [network]
 generateResolvConf = false
```

to the `/etc/wsl.conf` in your linux containers. You will need to reboot your container as outlined in https://superuser.com/questions/1126721/rebooting-ubuntu-on-windows-without-rebooting-windows, or you can reboot your pc.

Answer (score 0):

None of those solutions worked for me.
I finally make it work simply by doing an update of docker. (MAC OS)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue when trying to push to Docker.

1. I updated Docker Desktop (via the GUI)
2. I also ran `docker system prune` which prompts:

   WARNING! This will remove:
   - all stopped containers
   - all volumes not used by at least one container
   - all networks not used by at least one container
   - all dangling images

Confirm this by entering `yes`

Answer (score 0):

It could be temporary network issue. I had same issue. I would these two

- Re-run the command again
- Restart the Docker Desktop

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was getting this error while following the [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/) course. Since I was new to Docker I was actually building image by giving incorrect repository name( I was using Instructor username instead of mine docker repository username). When we push the image to Docker hub, use your docker repository name. Hence build image using your username.

> docker build . -t docker_username/example:latest

where . represent current directory where your Dockerfile resides.
Please first logged in your [docker repository](https://hub.docker.com/repositories) by using  Docker desktop in your system

*Hope this will solve someone's problem.*

Answer (score 0):

my solution was :

`docker image prune` and  `docker volume prune`

Answer (score 0):

Experienced this Error while I was trying to : `docker pull odoo`

and my solution was: `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Answer (score 0):

Just log in through the terminal and use the below command

```
docker login
```

Enter username and password

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck too, tried everything I could then I tried
these:
https://fedingo.com/how-to-uninstall-docker-in-ubuntu/

**Make sure you repeat step 1 and 2 mentioned in link untill step 1 shows nothing**

then procceed with step 3 and the next steps

then delete docker folder from here

/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/

then follow :

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so issue is likely you are using a Proxy!

This answer applies to Linux only..

You'll need to configure the proxy in two places. One is for pulling docker images and the other resolves network access from inside containers.

Use below script, adjust `ActiveProxyVar` and `corpdom` and save script and run!

```
#!/bin/bash

#Proxy
#Note: Doesn't always require user:pwd, can just be IP at bare minimum
ActiveProxyVar=user:pwd@IP:PORT

#Domain
corpdom=domain.org

#NoProxy
NOT_PROXY=127.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16,10.0.0.0/8,.$corpdom

httpproxyvar=http://$ActiveProxyVar/
httpsproxyvar=http://$ActiveProxyVar/

mkdir ~/.docker
cat << EOL >~/.docker/config.json
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "$httpproxyvar",
     "httpsProxy": "$httpsproxyvar",
     "noProxy": "$NOT_PROXY"
   }
 }
}
EOL

mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d

cat << EOL >/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=$httpproxyvar"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=$httpsproxyvar"
Environment="NO_PROXY=$NOT_PROXY"
Environment="http_proxy=$httpproxyvar"
Environment="https_proy=$httpsproxyvar"
Environment="no_proxy=$NOT_PROXY"
EOL

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
systemctl show --property Environment docker

docker run hello-world
```

Answer (score -1):

I have faced this error sometimes, my docker image is built smoothly before but when I have to remove all images ( even I do not make any change with the docker configuration files or any error in code). this still happens.

so I think that it may cause by the connection for it does a "Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/:....."

I have change DNS to google DNS 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 then it 's worked. 
good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I got this error from my own Internet connection. Switched to another provider, all good.

Answer (score -1):

Just add at the end of your shell command  `--dns 8.8.8.8`

Comment: It gives unknown flag error

Comment: @DeekshithAnand the flag does exist. If you execute `docker run --help` you will see the following messge: `--dns list                       Set custom DNS servers`, therefore it does exist

Answer (score -2):

Check in case VPN is blocking..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31231082)