# Ubuntu 18.04 - Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: tls: oversized record received with length 20527

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04, docker-ce

I am having issue with Docker on Ubuntu 18.04 with *docker-ce*. While pulling a container:

```
$ docker pull nginx
```

or while trying to login

```
$ docker login
```

I get the following message:

> Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/:
>   proxyconnect tcp: tls: oversized record received with length 20527

I also purged and reinstalled today with latest version but it didn't help. Does anyone get it resolved?

Comment: You use a proxy to access internet ?

Comment: Yes. I use a proxy but I had it set up and it was working perfectly. I got this problem 4 days ago.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had the same issue yesterday. 
Since I am behind a company proxy, I had to define the http-proxy for the docker daemon in:

```
/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf
```

The problem was, that I misconfigured the https_proxy, how it is described [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#set-the-environment-variables-manually).
I used *http**s**://* in the https_proxy environment variable, which caused this error.

This configuration works for me:

```
cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf

[Service]
Environment=http_proxy=http://IP:PORT/
Environment=no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1
Environment=https_proxy=http://IP:PORT/
```

Remember that you have to restart the docker daemon after changing this configuration. You can achieve this by using:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: The **https:...** was the actual culprit. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: You're a lifesaver, buddy!! Thanks a ton!

Comment: this doesnt work - https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/containers/docker/how-to-set-the-proxy-for-docker-on-ubuntu/, but yours - is good

Comment: just saved my life

Answer (score 1):

Run `docker logout` and try again. 
If fails then run `docker login` with `username`(not email) and `password`, this should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

mine was the date , fix the date correct this issue

```
sudo date -s "$(wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | grep Date: | cut -d' ' -f5-8)Z"
```