# ImagePullBackOff Error from mongo (Kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create a Kubernetes pod with the following config file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb-deployment
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        env:
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-username
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom: 
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-password
```

However, I get an ImagePullBackOff, and when I use kubectl describe pod, here's what's shown:

```
Name:         mongodb-deployment-8f6675bc5-jzmvw
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         minikube/192.168.64.2
Start Time:   Thu, 10 Dec 2020 16:30:21 +0800
Labels:       app=mongodb
              pod-template-hash=8f6675bc5
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Pending
IP:           172.17.0.3
IPs:
  IP:           172.17.0.3
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/mongodb-deployment-8f6675bc5
Containers:
  mongodb:
    Container ID:
    Image:          mongo
    Image ID:
    Port:           27017/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ErrImagePull
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME:  <set to the key 'mongo-root-username' in secret 'mongodb-secret'>  Optional: false
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'mongo-root-password' in secret 'mongodb-secret'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-w5ltt (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-w5ltt:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-w5ltt
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  115m  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/mongodb-deployment-8f6675bc5-jzmvw to minikube
  Normal   Pulling    115m  kubelet            Pulling image "mongo"
  Warning  Failed     114m  kubelet            Failed to pull image "mongo": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  Warning  Failed     114m  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    114m  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "mongo"
  Warning  Failed     114m  kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

I don't think it's a problem with the image/image name. Is there something wrong with my config file?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have deployed your config without any issues. Are you behind any proxy that might affect pulling images? Are you using private registry? Is there any output in `kubectl logs <pod-name>`?

Comment: @MariuszK. if one is behind a proxy what is the way to fix the issue described above? I've set the http_proxy environment variable, to no avail. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are few reasons for `ImagePullBackOff` error in Kubernetes, to determine it's cause you should run `kubectl describe pod`

```
Failed to pull image "mongo": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

This error means that image cannot be pulled from your container registry.

You can try to login to docker using `docker login` command.
If it fails you can try modifying your `/etc/resolv.conf` and adding *nameserver* `8.8.8.8` and then restarting docker using `sudo systemctl restart docker`.

Other cause might be using proxy or VPN connection. You can refer to answers [in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056365/error-get-https-registry-1-docker-io-v2-net-http-request-canceled-while-b)