# "Error response from daemon:proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup {proxy.example.com}: no such host". what should be placed instead of proxy.example.com?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, proxy, laravel-9

**Try-1:** I got this following error when I try to install laravel version 9 in my linux (ubuntu).

*docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)*

```
$ curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
Unable to find image 'laravelsail/php81-composer:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'docker run --help'.
bash: line 16: cd: example-app: No such file or directory
bash: line 18: ./vendor/bin/sail: No such file or directory
bash: line 19: ./vendor/bin/sail: No such file or directory

Get started with: cd example-app && ./vendor/bin/sail up
```

**Try-2:** I have beyond my company network when installing this and also I tried without being beyond my company network.so I changed my company network to my mobile network then I tried

*Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup proxy.example.com: no such host*

**Try-3:** When I changed http & https proxy to no proxy like this `Environment=no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1` and changed nameserver like this `nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4` I got below error.

*docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": x509: certificate is valid for *.orchardmile.com, orchardmile.com, not registry-1.docker.io*

Still same problem arises in different error message.

I have tried this solution : https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#httphttps-proxy in docker official documention and tried this also [Error "Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled" while building image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056365/error-get-https-registry-1-docker-io-v2-net-http-request-canceled-while-b) from stackflow.

> After reading above documentation I have one query that what does is **(proxy.example.com)** it mean in Environment variable in below config file.

**Should I change this `proxy.example.com` to anything regard my company gateway or proxy address something like that or just leave it as it is ?**

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:443/"
```

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/"
```

*Above snippet code is from the docker documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#httphttps-proxy*