# Unable to install Nginx Proxy Manager using Portainer on Synology

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, portainer

I followed this guide to install [Nginx Proxy Manager](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-and-use-portainer-for-docker-management-with-nginx-proxy-manager/) (NPM). When I try to create a stack, I get this error:

> failed to deploy a stack: npm-db Pulling npm-app Pulling npm-app Error
> npm-db Error Error response from daemon: Get
> "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while
> waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting
> headers)

I understand that the solution might be in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056365/error-get-https-registry-1-docker-io-v2-net-http-request-canceled-while-b) but how can I fix it in my case?

Answer (score 0):

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: proxy
    image: jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '81:81'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - data:/data
      - letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      
volumes:
  data: {}
  letsencrypt: {}
```